# Fullscreen div showing scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make div set to full screen with following CSS but always a scrollbar shows up and if I lessen width and height more than 100% then this is not working perfectly responsively. Is there a way I can make div  set to full screen responsively?

```
#fullScreen
{
  position: absolute; 
   text-align: left;
   left: 0px;
   top: 0px;
   width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
   z-index: 5;
   background-color: #FFDAB9;
   border: 4px solid #FF0000;
   border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Please show your sample HTML code

Comment: Did you try to use `overflow : none` , `width : 100%` and `height : 100%`?

Comment: @Arunkumar_Rock my html just have a div in a body with id assigned to mentioned in above CSS

Comment: @Jin if I set overflow to none I don't see red border on bottom and on right side

Comment: if width and height issues are solved, I suggest you one thing.
`width : calc(100% - 4px)` and `height : calc(100% - 4px)`

Comment: @Jin your suggestion worked perfectly! thanks

Comment: why change the width and use `calc` when you can just add `box-sizing:border-box` so that the border is included in the width of the element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is due to the increased size of border i.e 4px so just try this

```
#fullScreen
{ 
margin: 0px; 
position: absolute; 
text-align: left; 
left: 0px; 
top: 0px; 
width: calc(100% - 8px); 
height: calc(100% - 8px);
z-index: 5;
background-color: #FFDAB9; 
border: 4px solid #FF0000; 
border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This issue is related to how [CSS box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model) works.

The problem is that the border is considered, by default, outside the element ( an addition to the actual element ) . So your element has a width/height of `100vh/vw + 8px`. `8px` from the border values of `4px`.

You can easily fix this by adding [`box-sizing:border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) so that the border width is included in  the 'footprint' of the element

See below

```css
#fullScreen {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #FFDAB9;
  border: 4px solid #FF0000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="fullScreen">

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanatory answer, I was under the impression that border always count inside of the container but now its clear to me its considered to be  outside part of it with respect to given height and width.

Comment: @Rand glad i could help. Cheers ! :D